# Mocking window.navigator object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
var fake_navigator = {}
  for (var i in navigator) {
      fake_navigator[i] = navigator[i]
  }
  window.fake_navigator = fake_navigator
```

This creates a fake navigator object, however when I press "window.navigator" and "window.fake_navigator"
the only difference is the way it is printed.

[image]

There is a string "Navigator" infront, how can I replicate the same exact thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a name by just using an object literal, but you can if you make a class. Chrome (and most other browsers) will automatically add the class name before the object name when you're using an object that is an instance of that class. By making a class called `FakeNavigator`, you'll be able to see the class name as a prefix (run in browser console):

```
class FakeNavigator {
  constructor() {
    for (const i in navigator) {
      this[i] = navigator[i]
    }
  }
}

window.fake_navigator = new FakeNavigator();
```